# Upload image using PHP with return data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So the title isn't very clear as to what I am trying to do, but I don't know how else to define it in a  single line.

I have a website that will be used by several companies and they will be able to print/email out reports with their own logos on them. In order to email them, we need to store their logo on our server. This, of course, is where the upload part comes in, which is simple using PHP.

The issue I am banging my head against the wall about is that I need the file to be renamed to a 16 character guid and then the file name to be stored in a database table. I have set up a php (that works surprisingly well for someone not proficient in PHP) that creates the guid, checks the server to make sure there isn't already a file with that name, then renames the file, stores it, and echos the file name. Sounds good, right? Wrong!

For the life of me I cannot figure out a way to submit the file and be able to retrieve the file name. By using a form.submit(), a postback occurs interrupting my script and preventing me from retrieving the file name. I would use a $.post or &.ajax, but apparently files are the only thing they cannot submit, which is convenient because that is all I want it to do.

Any suggestions are GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would it be possible to have my javascript create the name, put it in a hidden text input in the form, and then have the PHP pull it from the submitted form data?

Answer (score 0):

You can submit files with ajax. You can use the `FileReader` API to get to the binary data of the file and send it. Send the binary data, reply with the filename (or whatever you need).

I'm omitting a code example because it's a little bit involved and I'm sure you can find one.

---

Here is an alternative solution:

When you submit the form do the follwing:

- create a hidden iframe on the page with an onload event
- create a new hidden form somewhere on the page which targets the iframe
- move the `file` element to this form. You can't copy the value because `file` inputs are protected.
- now submit the form and wait till the onload fires on the iframe then read the output

This works on older browsers. You won't be able to give nice feedback (like a progress indication) so I recommend you implement this as a fallback.

Comment: I thought about using FileReader, but it appears it has very limited browser support. This site being used by companies, sadly, a lot of them will be using various versions of IE :(

Comment: Ok .. there is an alternative solution, let me look it up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having my Javascript determine the filename, plug that into a hidden text input, sending all of my info to the database including the filename, then submitting the form. This worked perfectly.